# Not able to pass more than 1000 records to kendo gridview

Tags: c#, razor, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo Gridview to display some records. These records are in Json when retrieved from the database and stored in a list of the same class. I have no problem when the list is of count 1000, but any number above 1000 triggers an exception : "***Error** during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.*"

I have tried changing the maxJsonLength value in web.config and in appsettings as recommended in some of the solutions I found on stack overflow. But none of them work. This is my view:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)

.Name("grid")
.Scrollable()
.Filterable()
.Columns(columns =>
    {
        //Columns added here
    })
.Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
.Pageable(pageable => pageable
.Refresh(false)
.PageSizes(true)
.ButtonCount(3))
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .ServerOperation(false)
    .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(p => p.Id);
            model.Field(p => p.Id).Editable(false);

        })
    .Read(read => read.Action("Action", "Controller"))
    .PageSize(50)
    )
.Events(e => e.DataBound("selectDefault"))
```

Comment: Can you try setting `maxJsonLength` higher?

Comment: Not related, but do you really need 1000 or more records to show in UI?

Comment: Hi @Fabio, yes I need to display all the records that are stored in the database. for this purpose, I have added paging.

Comment: Then maybe you need server side pagination

Comment: Hi @devRicher, I have tried setting the maxJsonlength higher and tried using custom json serialization methods. But the problem is that I need to return a List containing json to the view and not raw Json.

Comment: @Dannyboi, so you don't need to show all records at one - consider server-side paging. Ithink it is only wasting of resources to load records which you not going to show

Comment: Check http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/binding/custom-binding

Comment: Okay, I will try server side paging and let you know @Fabio and  Mate

Comment: @Fabio, #Mate, I tried the server side paging. And I have made it work to a certain extent. The main fall back is that, we have to write extra code for each functionality of the grid view. Isn't there a shorter and easier solution for my problem?

Comment: Hey guys, I came to realize that the Json Lists that I was passing to the view had too many complex data types(i.e class objects) and that' the reason none of the solutions worked so I referred to a solution described in this [link](http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/troubleshoot/troubleshooting#error-during-serialization-or-deserialization-using-the-json-javascriptserializer)and created an intermediate view model. In this model I added all the necessary attributes that I wanted and passed it to view. It woks really fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to realize that the Json Lists that I was passing to the view had too many complex data types(i.e class objects and enums) and that was the reason none of the solutions worked. So I referred to a solution described in this [link](http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/troubleshoot/troubleshooting#error-during-serialization-or-deserialization-using-the-json-javascriptserializer) and created an intermediate view model. In this model I added all the necessary attributes that I wanted and passed it to view. It works really fine now